# If $\|(x_n, y_n)\|_W\to +\infty\quad\mbox{ as } n\to +\infty,$ we can assume WLOG that $\|x_n\|_{W^{1, p}}\to +\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain and let $p, q>1$. Consider $(x_n)_n\subset W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ and $(y_n)_n\subset W^{1, q}(\Omega)$.
Defined
$$W= W^{1, p}(\Omega)\times W^{1, q}(\Omega)\quad\mbox{ with } \|(x, y)\|_W = \|x\|_{W^{1, p}} +\|y\|_{W^{1, q}},$$
my question is the following.

If we assume that
$$\|(x_n, y_n)\|_W\to +\infty\quad\mbox{ as } n\to +\infty,$$
it can be assumed that at least one between $\|x_n\|_{W^{1, p}}$ and $\|y_n\|_{W^{1, q}}$ goes at $+\infty$? I mean, it is possible to say:

"Assume $\|(x_n, y_n)\|_W\to +\infty$. Thus, without loss of generality, we can suppose that $\|x_n\|_{W^{1, p}}\to +\infty$"?

I hope someone could clarify that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I meant at least one of them, no matter if $x_n$ or $y_n$. In your example it should be true for $y_n$, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you mean "both". So obviously, one of them will go to $\infty $ (a simple proof by contradiction should be enough to see it ;-) )

Comment: @Surb thank you very much! :-)